# button value not displayed -javascript

Tags: javascript, html, properties

I have a html doc, I'm trying to build simple calc

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.buttons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #ba1a1a;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: large;
}
.cbuttons {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ba1a1a;
  moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: large;
}
td{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="padding-top: 300px;padding-left: 300px;">
   <table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
         <input type="button" class="cbuttons" value="CE">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="7">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="8">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="9">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="4">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="6">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" class="buttons" value="3">
      </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="jsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

and here is my **jsfile.js** file

```
window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            element.onclick = function() {
                alert(element.value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the value of button, I'm getting **3** in **alert(element.value);**
**what I want :** when 3 is pressed 3 must me alerted
Correct me If i'm wrong with code.

Thanks

Comment: You want in keyboard 3 keypress alert 3  like: http://jsfiddle.net/uzjqh3r2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of element.value, use this.value.

```js
window.onload = function() {

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")
        
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
          
            element.onclick = function() {
                alert(this.value);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.buttons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #ba1a1a;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: large;
}
.cbuttons {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ba1a1a;
  moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: large;
}
td{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding-top: 300px;padding-left: 300px;">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="button" class="cbuttons" value="CE">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="7">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="8">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="9">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="4">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="5">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="6">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="1">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="2">
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="3">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<script src="jsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: then why **3** is alerted for all clicks on  **element.value**?

Comment: it is because, 3 is the last element during iteration and it is set for the element object. Also, during the element.onclick, you should use (this) which gives the object of clicked element instead of the last element in the iteration.